# How can I make the Dropdown in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, dropdown

I'm a beginner for Django.

I'm trying to make the Dropdown to change the table for searching something.

I don't know how to make it....

example)
when I choose the A in dropdown, It has to search A table.
when I choose the B in dropdown, It has to search B table.

view.py

```py
class SearchFormView(FormView, LoginRequiredMixin):

    form_class = SearchForm
    template_name = 'purchase_order/order.html'

    print(form_class)
    def form_valid(self, form):

        searchWord = form.cleaned_data['search_word']
        print(searchWord)
        cat_list = Catalog_info.objects.filter(Q(CAT_ID__icontains=searchWord)|Q(CAT__icontains=searchWord)|Q(CATEGORY__icontains=searchWord)|Q(CAT_NAME__icontains=searchWord)).distinct()

        context={}
        context['form']=form
        context['search_term']=searchWord
        context['object_list']=cat_list

        return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.Form):

    search_word = forms.CharField(label='Search Word')
```

Please advise me.

Comment: In my opinion, you need to create a dropdown table in the HTML template, put that inside a form and once it submits, pass the data selected in the dropdown to the view that is being called next. There you can access the data that was sent in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ChoiceField` for the choices and it uses `Select` as default widget. Example:

```py
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    YOUR_CHOICES = [('1', 'First'), ('2', 'Second')]

    search_word = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YOUR_CHOICES)
```

here is the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/